# Self-hosted Gitlab CE, connect with Visual Studio Code Docker Plugin: Auth-Problem

Tags: docker, authentication, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I have a self hosted Gitlab-Server, that is working fine (over `https`). I use this Gitlab to host Docker Images.

I usually work fine via CLI: I can login with `docker login ...` as I saved a ssh-key, and I can do all the rest of the work.

Now I've installed the Docker-Plugin within Visual Studio Code. The Plugin has an option to connect to registries. One option is to connect to `gitlab.com` and this works with my gitlab.com-Account.

There is also an option to connect to a generic registry. Unfortunately, this does not work with my self-hosted Gitlab-Server. I put in the same credentials as I do via CLI, but I get a permission denied.

I have no idea why. Do I need some configuration at the Gitlab-Server? Or in Visual Studio Code? Is the auth within VSC any different then from the CLI?

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a personal access token instead of the user/password to see if it makes a difference (also it's safer)

Other than that there seem to be still some problems using gitlab as a registry in self installs from vscode, as they seem to be doing a major refactor on this part of the plugin, there's an issue you can follow [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/869)

My experience so far 31/08/21 has been that authentication was working but I got stuck at "Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body"

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I have the same error

Comment: no, unfortunately I couldn't still using the docker client